# CSS Div and image max-width

Tags: css

I want to make an image fit a div whilst maintaining its aspect ratio. I have seen other posts where it is mentioned to use `max-width:100%;`.

when the image is smaller than the div, it works fine, the image is kept to a size within the div. But when the image is larger, it simply gets out of the div.

```
<img src="testimg.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height:100%;"/>
```

But when i use this code:

```
<img src="testimg.jpg" width=540px/>
```

The large image is resized to fit the div but does not maintain its aspect ratio.

Can any one advise on the above issue please?

Comment: It is supposed to maintain aspect ratio, unless you using some styles for height too. Can you provide jsfiddle/codepen example of this problem?

Comment: Edit your code and format the code you have written.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to paste the code here. Pleae add it.

Answer (score 1):

This should mantain the aspect ratio:

```
<img src="testimg.jpg" style="max-width:100%; max-height:auto;"/>
```

I do not recomend using inline CSS, instead separate it:

**CSS:**

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="testimg.jpg" />
```

---

For the second part of your code, the width attribute represents the **exact** width of your image, not the maximum width. And in HTML5, the value must in pixels but without `px` suffix:

```
<img src="testimg.jpg" width="540" />
```

Again this is not a good practice, always use CSS to manipulate the HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

max-width:100% works only if the img tag has not width and height attributes, because they prevail on max-width. So please try to remove the width="540"

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following CSS

div{ovwerflow:none;}

img{width:100%; max-height

Comment: Please proof-read your own answer before posting it. Examine the icons above the edit field to find out how to format code in your answer.